# Can't understand the behavior of jquery bind & live with click event

Tags: jquery

[fiddle of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/9gKYC/)

```
$('div').not('#logs').each(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#" + id).bind('click', function () {
        $('#logs').append('\n' + $(this).attr('id') + '\n');
    });
});

$(".test").live('click', function () {
    alert('from x');
});
```

what i would have done is like, created some divs and would have looped through all the divs using each function and would have binded a click event for each of the divs.

there are spans inside each divs of class name 'test' to which i would have binded live functionality as specified above. when the spans are clicked, only the alert 'from x' should  appear but i can't understand the behavior.

The behavior is like, the bind functionality is also working and the live functionality is also working.

please apologize my sentence formation mistakes, i'm bit low in explaining the issue.
waiting for the explanation of the behavior.

Thanks

Comment: Events bubble up the DOM tree. So when you click a `span` inside a `div` element, both event handlers are triggered. Learn more about events: http://learn.jquery.com/events/, http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html. FYI, you can simplify the event binding to `$('div').not('#logs').bind('click', function() { ... });`, no need for `.each`.

Comment: sidenote : `live()` has been deprecated and removed.

Comment: can you guys please suggest how to do this properly
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events bubble up the DOM tree, firing any handlers bound the the element along the way.

You would normally stop the propagation by calling `event.stopPropagation()` however since the `.live()` method handles events once they have propagated to the top of the document, your parent elements `click()` method will have already been called.

You can make you code work as expected by changing it to the following:

```
$(".test").on('click', function (event) {
    alert('from x');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

If you really need to use `.live()` for example if you are creating these dynamically, then instead using `.bind()` for your parent element, use `.live()` also, e.g.:

```
$('div').not('#logs').each(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#" + id).live('click', function () {
        $('#logs').append('\n' + $(this).attr('id') + '\n');
    });
});

$(".test").live('click', function (event) {
    alert('from x');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

You can also use the more favoured '.on()' method instead of the depreciated `.live()` as follows:

```
$('div').not('#logs').each(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(document).on('click', "#" + id, function () {
        $('#logs').append('\n' + $(this).attr('id') + '\n');
    });
});

$(document).on('click', ".test", function (event) {
    alert('from x');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: The solution works, thanks a lot bro, was scratching my head for almost 2hrs i guess :)

but why Sushanth 2nd method on is not working.

Comment: on method is not stopping the event propagation.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gKYC/4/)

Comment: @Beast that's because you are still using .click().  See http://jsfiddle.net/U75Dz/2/

Answer (score 0):

Events are bound to the elements that exist on the page at the time events are attached.

In your case the elements were always present on the page when this happened. So both the ways of binding events would work.

The 2nd case is event delegation which is used to bind events to dynamically created events, i.e elements which are attached to the `DOM` after the events are bound. So when you use `live` to bind the event , the event is attached to the document which is always present. Which uses the concept of event bubbling

Maybe elements inserted to the dom after an `Ajax` request

**Code**

You don't need the `$.each` loop as the selector selects all the elements matched by it

```
$('div').not('#logs').click( function () {
        $('#logs').append('\n' + this.id + '\n');
});

// live has be deprecated to delegate events as of jQuery 1.7
// use on instead to bind the events for event delegation
$(document).on('click', ".test", function () {
    alert('from x');
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/9gKYC/3/)**

Comment: yes in my case, the elements are dynamically inserted and removed.
is there any proper way to achieve this

Comment: i just did it. didn't work out 

http://jsfiddle.net/9gKYC/1/

here's the updated fiddle

Comment: This is not using the `$.each` which is not required in this case to bind the events. SO you are cutting down 2 lines of unnecessary code that is not required

Comment: Thanks man, but still the on method is not working for me.
[here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gKYC/4/)